# winrt windows 8 change .net framework target

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

How can I change .Net Framework version in windows store application from 4.5.1 to 4.5 ? Seems like it is only possible when you are creating new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the .NET framework version on Windows Store apps - you can only choose the targeted Windows version (8.0 or 8.1) like shown in Filip's answer. What's do you want to change the framework version?

Answer (score 1):

Compare empty 8.0 and 8.1 project files and you'll see some very simple difference to change - possibly just

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```

to

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>11</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```

Comment: I need to change .net framework target from 4.5.1 to 4.5 . windows 8.1 works with .net framework 4.5 too.

Comment: I don't think that should be necessary for the project itself. If you remove the 8.1/12 lines - the project should work with .NET 4.5. Now if you have some NuGet packages - that might be a different issue. I'd recommend removing those and adding the 4.5 ones again after you've modified the csproj file.